# Parallel data.table operations

Tags: r, data.table, large-data, posixct

I have a data.table object in my script and I need to convert a separate date and time column to a POSIXct object. I am using `fastPOSIXct()` to convert to `POSIXct`. I find some bottlenecks with `data.table` operations to do this. The main problems are concatenating the strings before converting to `POSIXct` and the `POSIXct` conversion itself. I am using `stri_c()` to do `paste0()` faster. Is there any way to parallelize this computation to speed it up? The csv file being read is a large file about 2gb.

[data.table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXGnN.png)

```
  index = match(file, csv_files)
  print(paste0("Starting File #", index, ". Running Active Future Filter."))
  csv1 = fread(file = file)
  # create row for date in Date format
  csv1[, date := as.Date(integer())]
  csv1[, trade_date := as.character(trade_date)]
  csv1[, date := as.Date(trade_date[1], "%Y%m%d"), by = trade_date]
  csv1[, active_exp := character()]
  csv1[, active_exp := get.active.future(date = date[1]), by = date]
  nrow(csv1)
  csv1 = csv1[csv1$active_exp == as.character(csv1$contract_delivery_date),]
  # Add POSIXct
  # keep only essential columns
  csv1 = csv1[,-c(3, 6, 9, 23, 11:21)]
  print(paste0("Running POSIX"))
  # establish date-time POSIX for tick
  csv1[, date_time_char := as.character()]
  # creates date time character type to be converted to POSIXct
  csv1[, date_time_char := stri_c(date[1], trade_time[1], sep = " "), by = list(date, trade_time)]
  
  # convert date time character type to POSIXct
  csv1[, date_time := fastPOSIXct(date_time_char[1]), by = date_time_char]
  # time shift for date when time is between 17:00 and 00:00
  print("Making time adjustment")
  csv1[,adj_date_time := time.shift(date_time[1]), by = date_time]
  # convert date
  csv1[, date := as.Date(adj_date_time, tz = "UTC")]
  # overwrite current loaded file
```

Comment: Welcome! Please make your examples reproducible. Also, regarding the question, I am not sure it is "some bottlenecks with data.table operations to do this" as much as it is converting from strings to ```POSIXct``` is slow.

Comment: This seems to be relevant https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4572

Comment: @Cole apologies for not being able to include data, it is paid for and cannot be posted on public forum. I can send str() or any other info.

Comment: Reproducible does not mean sharing private data. It means taking the time to provide a dataset that can simulate the issue.

Comment: @Cole posted an answer using your code and shared dput output of data.

Comment: hi, do you really need the `by` when pasting and using `fastPOSIXct`?

Comment: @chinsoon12 I thought the same thing, but I thought it may be a performance thing. If you have a lot of repeated dates, it may be quicker to group by the string and then do the conversion on one string rather than all of them.

Comment: that looks like SPX future transactions ticker data so i suspect there are trade_time goes down to milliseconds

Answer (score 3):

This should help (untested because the example was not reproducible):

```r
index = match(file, csv_files)

csv1 = fread(file = file)
# create row for date in Date format
csv1[, trade_date := as.character(trade_date)]
csv1[,
     c("date", "active_exp") := {
       date1 = as.Date(.BY[[1L]], "%Y%m%d")
       active_exp = get.active.future(date1)
       .(date1, active_exp)},
     by = trade_date]

csv1 = csv1[active_exp == contract_delivery_date), -c(3, 6, 9, 23, 11:21)]

# creates date time character type to be converted to POSIXct
csv1[, 
     c("date_time", "adj_date_time", "date") = {
       date_time = fastPOSIXct(stri_c(.BY[[1L]]), .BY[[2L]], sep = " ")
       adj_date_time = time.shift(date_time)
       date = as.Date(adj_date_time, tz = "UTC")
     }
     , by = .(date, trade_time)
]
```

There were multiple places where grouping was done on more-or-less the same data. Each time we are grouping it means we are calling `forder()` and having to group the data. Instead, we can just try to do everything at once.

To make this even faster, I recommend only `fread`ing the columns that you need. Related, after importing the file, I would make the filter `active_exp == contract_delivery_date`.

*Edit*
One thing you could look at is using `IDate` and `ITime` to make a `POSIXct` column. The slowest part would likely be the `stri_c / paste` followed by either the grouping or the `fasttime::fastPOSIXct`. Here is how to avoid the paste, although it relies on some `Rcpp` to help parse the timestamp column.

```r
Rcpp::cppFunction("
IntegerVector to_time(std::vector< std::string > x) {
  //for format hh:mm:ss 
  int n = x.size();
  IntegerVector out(n);
  
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){;
    const std::string xi = x[i]; 
    const int hour = stoi(xi.substr(0, 2));
    const int minute = stoi(xi.substr(3, 2));
    const int second = stoi(xi.substr(6, 2));
    out[i] = hour * 60 * 60 + minute * 60 + second;
  }
  return(out);
}
")

csv1[,
     date_time := {
       date1 = as.IDate(as.character(trade_date), "%Y%m%d")
       time = as.ITime(to_time(trade_time))
       .(as.POSIXct(date1, time, tz = "UTC"))
     }]
```

When replicating the small data set a million times, this takes 3s vs. `fasttime::fastPOSIXct()` taking 20s. Will post benchmarking below.

You should also consider removing the `by =`  part of your original posting. If there are a lot of repeated date times, then yes, grouping by a group can sometimes be more performant. But if there are a lot of unique datetimes, you would likely be better off skipping the grouping step.

```r
csv1 = csv1[rep(seq_len(.N), 1e6L)]

## for use in different use cases
date_col = as.Date(as.character(csv1$trade_date), "%Y%m%d")
IDate_col = as.IDate(date_col)
hour_col = as.ITime(to_time(csv1$trade_time))
bench::mark(
 as_char_to_date = as.Date(as.character(csv1$trade_date), "%Y%m%d")
 ,
 as.ITime(to_time(csv1$trade_time))
 ,
 as_date_to_idate = as.IDate(date_col)
 , as.POSIXct(IDate_col, hour_col, tz = "UTC")
 ,  use_fasttime = fasttime::fastPOSIXct(paste(date_col, csv1$trade_time), "UTC")
 , check = FALSE
)

## # A tibble: 5 x 13
##   expression                                       ## min   median `itr/sec`
##   <bch:expr>                                  <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl>
## 1 as_char_to_date                                3.03s    3.03s    0.330 
## 2 as.ITime(to_time(csv1$trade_time))             2.03s    2.03s    0.494 
## 3 as_date_to_idate                              13.2ms   13.5ms   23.1   
## 4 as.POSIXct(IDate_col, hour_col, tz = "UTC") 929.14ms 929.14ms    1.08  
## 5 use_fasttime                                  20.39s   20.39s    0.0490
```

Comment: This sped up the process significantly but still takes (unreasonably imo) long.

Comment: See edit.  Also note that the ```Rcpp``` can made parallel relatively easily with ```OpenMP```. I tested it with 8 threads and it was about 4 times faster on the ```ITime``` step for about 1.8s for going from Date -> POSIXct vs 18s for Date -> fasttime.

Comment: This works beautifully. Edited one of the parentheses `date1 = as.IDate(as.character(trade_date, "%Y%m%d"))` to `date1 = as.IDate(as.character(trade_date), "%Y%m%d")`

Comment: Edited. You can feel free to accept. Also, I would delete your answer although maybe editing your question to include the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
As suggested by @Cole, I used this C++ function and IDate and ITime to speed this up. I have not benchmarked this but can say it runs about 20x faster than the previous code. Code is below.

```
for(file in csv_files){

  index = match(file, csv_files)
  csv1 = fread(file = file, drop = c(3, 6, 9, 23, 11:21))
  
  options(warn = -1)
  # get date and time and classify as POSIXct
  csv1[,
       c("date_time", "date", "time") := {
         
         time = as.ITime(to_time(trade_time))
         date1 = as.IDate(as.character(trade_date), "%Y%m%d")
         if(hour(time) >= 17){
            POSIX = as.POSIXct(date1, time, tz = "UTC") - days(1)
            .(POSIX, as.Date(POSIX), time)
         }else{
            POSIX = as.POSIXct(date1, time, tz = "UTC")
            .(POSIX, as.Date(POSIX), time)
         }
       }]
  options(warn = 0)
  # covert trade date to character format
  csv1[, trade_date := as.character(trade_date)]
  # run active_exp
  csv1[,
       active_exp := get.active.future(as.Date(date[1])),
       by = date]
  # filter only active future
  csv1 = csv1[active_exp == as.character(contract_delivery_date)]
  # write file
  file_path = paste0("C:/Users/ocean/Documents/CME Data/Active Daily Data CSVs/", index, ".csv")
  fwrite(csv1, file = file_path)
  
  print(paste0("Progress = ", round(index/length(csv_files), 3)*100, "%"))
}
```

OLD:
I used the code provided by @Cole but was still running it for quite a long time. I edited the code slightly to fix some syntax, below.
file = csv_files[1]
index = match(file, csv_files)

```
csv1 = fread(file = file, drop = c(3, 6, 9, 23, 11:21))
# create row for date in Date format
csv1[, trade_date := as.character(trade_date)]
csv1[,
     c("date", "active_exp") := {
       date1 = as.Date(.BY[[1L]], "%Y%m%d")
       active_exp = get.active.future(date1)
       .(date1, active_exp)},
     by = trade_date]

csv1 = csv1[active_exp == contract_delivery_date]

# creates date time character type to be converted to POSIXct
csv1[, 
     c("date_time", "adj_date_time", "date") := {
       date_time = fastPOSIXct(stri_c(.BY[[1L]], .BY[[2L]], sep = " "))
       adj_date_time = time.shift(date_time)
       date = as.Date(adj_date_time, tz = "UTC")
     }
     , by = .(date, trade_time)
]
```

To try to offer a reproducible example the `dput()` of the data is below.

```
    structure(list(trade_date = c(20200115L, 20200115L, 20200115L, 
20200115L, 20200115L, 20200115L), trade_time = c("17:00:00", 
"17:00:00", "17:00:00", "17:00:00", "17:00:00", "17:00:00"), 
    trade_sequence_number = c(9028350L, 9028357L, 9028366L, 9028394L, 
    9028397L, 9028400L), session_indicator = c("E", "E", "E", 
    "E", "E", "E"), ticker_symbol = c("ES", "ES", "ES", "ES", 
    "ES", "ES"), future_option_index_indicator = c("F", "F", 
    "F", "F", "F", "F"), contract_delivery_date = c(2003L, 2003L, 
    2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L), trade_quantity = c(176L, 0L, 
    3L, 2L, 4L, 10L), strike_price = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), trade_price = c(3287.75, 3287.75, 3288, 3288, 3288, 3288
    ), ask_bid_type = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), indicative_quote_type = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), market_quote = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), close_open_type = c("", "O", "", "", "", ""), valid_open_exception = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), post_close = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), cancel_code_type = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), insert_code_type = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), fast_late_indicator = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), cabinet_indicator = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), book_indicator = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), entry_date = c(20200114L, 
    20200114L, 20200114L, 20200114L, 20200114L, 20200114L), exchange_code = c("XCME", 
    "XCME", "XCME", "XCME", "XCME", "XCME")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001ef853c1ef0>)
```

Given the file's size (2-4gb for 38 files) do I just need to learn C++ or let this run overnight?

Comment: Can you control  the data provided in the csv? ```fread``` will take a date in the format of ```yyyy-mm-dd``` and automatically read it as an ```IDate``` format.

Comment: @Cole I cannot control the data as it is pulled from a database using cURL API request